# Issues with fonts, line spacing and margin in thesis

Tags: fonts, margins

I have the following main thesis tex file :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\input{preamble.tex}

\allowdisplaybreaks % allow page breaks
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.70\textwidth]{logo} \\[2cm]

{ \large \bfseries Perfect Triangles : Rational points on Elliptic Curves }\\
Shahrina Ismail \\
\{B.Sc, M.Sc\} \\[7cm]
{\em A thesis submitted for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy at\\
The University of Queensland in 2017} \\
School of Mathematics and Physics

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{abstract}
\doublespacing
A Heron triangle is a triangle \\
\end{abstract}

\onehalfspacing
\input{UQPreliminary.tex}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/Introduction}

\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Background and Methodology}\label{chap:2}
\input{chapters/chapter2}

\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Values of $\delta(\mu)$}\label{chap:3}
\input{chapters/chapter3}

\onehalfspacing
\chapter{\textbf{$\mu \in Y=\{-1,0,3 \}$}}\label{chap:4}
\input{chapters/chapter4}

\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Existence of a Suitable Pair \textbf{$(M,k_0)$}}\label{chap:5}
\input{chapters/chapter5}

\onehalfspacing
%\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}
```

I have been advised by the Graduate school that "`\input{UQPreliminary.tex}`" which contains their preliminary pages set by the university does not meet their requirement.

1. First they said it is still not 1.5 spacing when I clearly placed a "`\onehalfspacing`" command above "`\input{UQPreliminary.tex}`". But according to them it is not.
2. They said I need to use either Arial or Times New Roman as the font type in my thesis. So I use "`\usepackage{mathptmx}`" and it did change the preliminary pages to Times New Roman, unfortunately messed up all the mathematics symbol I am using in my thesis for instance `\mathcal{S}` is a different symbol now. Is there a way I can fix this? or any advice of the best way I can deal with this to make sure the thesis has Arial or Times New Roman font but does not mess up the mathematics symbol I have.
3. Another issue is regarding the margin. It should be 20mm margins consistently throughout the thesis. How do I set this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Maybe they mean "Microsoft Word 1.5 spacing", which you get with \setstretch{1.5}.
2. `mathptmx` is considered outdated. The recommended replacement is using the packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`. You will not get the real Times New Roman, but some Times clone. It depends on how picky they are, whether that is acceptable.

Or you could try to use `lualatex` or `xelatex` and the with `fontspec` you can use the real fonts. But that might give some clashes with other packages that you use. And you might still have to use `newtxmath` for the math. Then you have to use `fontspec` with the `no-math` option.

Math symbols that you don't like can be changed with `\DeclareMathSymbol`.

3. For the margins, use \usepackage{margin=20mm]{geometry}. You probably also want to set some other parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1) worked well!! Great!! . For point 2) can I some how use newtxtext or newtxmath only for "\input{UQPreliminary.tex}". Because the grad school said the rest of the thesis can be of any font, it is just the preliminary pages they care about.

Comment: Also I can seem to use \usepackage{margin=20mm]{geometry}   because it clashes with \setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

Comment: Yes, of course, if you set the margins and the paper size then the `\textwidth` and the `\...margins` follow from that. But you can still set `\parskip` and `\parindent`.